# Insert sub-string at a particular location in all elemnets of data-frame (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

This is the content of my csv file:

```
filename,wid,hei,obj,num
Video_7_035.jpg,640,480,face,333
Video_7_035.jpg,640,480,face,333
Video_7_035.png,640,480,face,333
Video_4_0383.jpg,640,480,face,333
Video_4_0383.png,640,480,face,333
Video_4_0179.jpg,640,480,face,333
Video_4_0099.jpg,640,480,face,333
Video_4_0099.png,640,480,face,333
```

I want to insert a string `str_suff = "_tile"` before the .jpg or .png of each element in filename. So the output should become:

```
filename,wid,hei,obj,num
Video_7_035_tile.jpg,640,480,face,333
Video_7_035_tile.jpg,640,480,face,333
Video_7_035_tile.png,640,480,face,333
Video_4_0383_tile.jpg,640,480,face,333
Video_4_0383_tile.png,640,480,face,333
Video_4_0179_tile.jpg,640,480,face,333
Video_4_0099_tile.jpg,640,480,face,333
Video_4_0099_tile.png,640,480,face,333
```

I use python3. Using the dataframes from pandas, this is the closest I have got:

```
arr = input_df['filename']
arrstr2 = arr.add_suffix('_tile')
print(arrstr2)
```

This prints:

```
0_tile Video_7_035.jpg
1_tile Video_7_035.jpg
2_tile Video_7_035.png
...
```

which is not what I want.

Additionally, I converted `arr` to string using: `arrstr = arr.to_string(index=False)`

This prints arrstr as all the file names:

```
Video_7_035.jpg
Video_7_035.jpg
Video_7_035.png
...
```

From this array, I am not able to figure out how to insert the string `"_tile"` at the required location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.split` and list comprehension

```
df['filename'] = [i[0] + '_tile.' + i[1] for i in df['filename'].str.split(".")]
```

Output

```
                filename  wid  hei   obj  num
0   Video_7_035_tile.jpg  640  480  face  333
1   Video_7_035_tile.jpg  640  480  face  333
2   Video_7_035_tile.png  640  480  face  333
3  Video_4_0383_tile.jpg  640  480  face  333
4  Video_4_0383_tile.png  640  480  face  333
5  Video_4_0179_tile.jpg  640  480  face  333
6  Video_4_0099_tile.jpg  640  480  face  333
7  Video_4_0099_tile.png  640  480  face  333
```

Comment: Thanks, additionally, how can I concatenate the same data frame N number of times? I.e. if I want df to be concatenated 3 times, I obtain 24 rows, with same data repeated three times. 

Currently I am creating three copies of the csv file and: 
`all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))` with  `df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files)`  `concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: side note, did you mark the question as answered? it seems unmarked now

Comment: to repeat the dataframe N times: `pd.concat([df]*N)`

Comment: Sorry, it's accepted now. Thanks a lot! One last query:
If I want to perform this operation `df['filename'] = [i[0] + '_tile.' + i[1] for i in df['filename'].str.split(".")]` to only 50-100 rows, how should I go about it?

Comment: there are many ways, first 50 would be temp = [i[0] + '_tile.' + i[1] for i in df.head(50)['filename'].str.split(".")] But a more general approach would be to use .iloc: ... for i in df.loc[:50, 'filename'] ... – Yuca 27 mins ago

Comment: Again, sorry, but it gives me an error when I use ".head" or ".loc". 

I am aware of .loc, I use it in a case like: `df.loc[0:N-1,'ymin'] += 1000`

Comment: the head version had a syntax mistake, the loc version works just fine. So not sure how you're using them but feel free to post another question instead :)